# How to create parallel connections and queries to db in bash script

Tags: linux, database, bash, oracle, parallel-processing

I have an oracle db on my Linux machine.
A single sql query (1 connection) via bash is as follows:

```
su - oracle
sqlplus <dbuser>/<dbpass>
select * from cat;
exit
```

I'm trying to run parallel queries via bash, the following script is for running 10000 connections in parallel (Correct me if i'm wrong):

```
for i in $(seq 1 10000); do echo "select * from <tableName>;" | sqlplus <dbuser>/<dbpass>&done
```

I would like to make this code more robust and flexible, for the sake of example i want to add a sleep between each of the following command:

- Create a connection
- Create a table (Unique to this connection, i as index for example)
- Select data from the table
- Close the connection

The following code is my attempt of doing so: (Not working)

```
for i in $(seq 1 10000); 
do 
   echo "CREATE TABLE test+i (id NUMBER NOT NULL);" 
   sleep 2
   echo "select * from test+i"
   sleep 2 
   echo "DROP TABLE test+i" | sqlplus <dbuser>/<dbpass>& 
done
```

1) Syntactically, how should i write it?

2) How can i know how many queries/connections succeeded and how many failed?

3) How can i know how many connections actually ran in parallel

Answer (score 1):

1) you can use `(` and `)` to group command into subshells, and send them background:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10000); 
do
   echo "CREATE TABLE test_$i (id NUMBER NOT NULL);
   !sleep 2
   select * from test_$i;
   !sleep 2
   DROP TABLE test_$i;" | sqlplus <dbuser>/<dbpass> &
done
```

2) you can set up error handling after each sqlplus call (examine output or exit value)

```
     echo "CREATE TABLE test_$i (id NUMBER NOT NULL);"  | sqlplus <dbuser>/<dbpass> 2>&1 | grep -i error
```

3) you can use the `jobs` command to examine how many job is running in the background:

```
> sleep 100 &
[1] 31642
> jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &
```

Comment: Those commands you wrote in 1, is doing the following: do action and disconnect, do another action and disconnect, do another and disconnect, i want the 3 actions to happen via 1 connection, connect -> do 3 queries -> disconnect

Comment: I modified the post, you can call out to shell from sqlplus using `!`

Answer (score 1):

10000 jobs in parallel will often cause overflow. By setting 'WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE' `sqlplus` will return an error, if the SQL fails. GNU Parallel can then re-run the query.

my.log will show if the query failed after rerunning 3 times.

```
doit() {
   i=$1
   (echo "WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE CREATE TABLE test$i (id NUMBER NOT NULL);"
    sleep 2
    echo "WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE select * from test$i;"
    sleep 2
    echo "WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE DROP TABLE test$i;") |
     sqlplus <dbuser>/<dbpass>
}
export -f doit

seq 1 10000 | parallel --joblog my.log -j0 --retries 3 doit
```